# Custom fonts not working in Swift programmatically but working with xib/Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4, ios12

I am using a custom font in my application. I added the fonts "ttf" file to the resource folder and made it available for all the target. I verified, it was in the copy bundle resource and in the plist file with proper naming conventions.

I used FontBook Mac app to take the PostScript name of the custom font and copy pasted to my code to avoid type errors.

I'm able to select the font in Storyboard/xib and its reflecting in the UI. But when I tried to do it programmatically like without using designers like below the font is not reflected in the UI.

The notable point here is I have 4 buttons and if I set font for one button via storyboard and set the same font for other buttons via programmatically, then its working.

```
  exploreAppBtn.titleLabel?.font =  UIFont(name: "SansOfcMed-Bold", size: 20)
```

Is it an Xcode issue? Anyone have faced it? If yes, whats the solution?

Added the Plist file and Build phases screenshots

[image]

[image]

Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Comment: what did you try to pass instead of CustomFontName?

Comment: CustomFontName is just a string constant in constant file.

Answer (score 2):

1. Check if custom font is added in info.plist file with proper naming conventions.
2. Add extension

   ```
   extension UIFont {
       class func fontName(size: CGFloat) -> UIFont {
           return UIFont.init(name: "CustomFontName", size: size)!
        }
   }
   ```

Usage:

```
exploreAppButton.titleLabel?.font =  UIFont.fontName(size: 16)
```

Comment: Yes, font is listed in the plist file and I could able to do it via designers. Problem only when accessing through code.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please clarify how exactly you create CustomFontName

Maybe the font name is not valid

Valid fonts name you can find with the code.

```
let familyFontsNames = UIFont.familyNames

for familyName in familyFontsNames {
    let fontsName = UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: familyName)
    for fontName in fontsName {
        print(fontName) // Prints list of all available fonts name. And you should use the name.
    }
}
```

Try to check if your CustomFontName exists in the list.

Comment: CustomFontName is just a String constant in constants file. I tried giving the font PostScript name directly also, but no use. The font is listed in the family font names list.

Answer (score 0):

I tried more than 25 fonts, probably Swift does not support some fonts.(possibly a localization problem?)

- ✅ Google Fonts work.
- ✅ Cyrillic fonts work.

But custom fonts with a non-standard style or
style/effect are not displayed at all.